# Convert SecretBytes to String and viceversa

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, callable

I am trying to get zip file content into a secretbytes and converting it to bytes and writing it to a file.zip, Zip is properly working.

When i convert secretbytes to string then to secretbytes and then to bytes and writing it to a file.zip, now that zip is kind of corrupted. able to see all the files inside the zip but not able to access them.

```
String data1 = new String(sec.getPlainData());
byte []data = SecretBytes.fromString(data1).getPlainData();
```